# How to affix a stud to the floor/wall when tanking a basement without 'breaking the seal?'

Tags: basement, waterproofing

I'm looking into tanking a cellar/basement. It is not prone to flooding, only damp coming through the walls and floor, so the basic idea is of tanking to form a waterproof layer and then probably building a timber stud as a nice clean wall.

But how can you screw/bolt/nail your stud to the floor and external walls, since the central premise of tanking is there must be *no holes*, and this will breach the membrane or whatever?

Is there a special fixing type/technique I need to know the name of?

Comment: Do you believe “tanking” will seal the basement? Investigate swimming pools with rigid bottoms and liners. (If not filled with water the water gets in between the liner and the structure. If concerned about water ingress the best thing to do is seal from the outside and pump the water away from the foundation. Every inside sealant I have seen used has failed to some point. If there is no water to enter there are no leaks.

Comment: All that being said, your timber will be exposed to the water if it bolts into damp bricks or whatever. Screws will rust, etc. I'm not sure if treated timber and stainless screws are sufficient

Comment: It is normal to use a barrier and or treated lumber in contact with concrete. I have used galvanized fasteners for almost 50 years and those buildings are still standing.

Comment: @Ed Beal I agree.  Additionally since composite decking came on the market, I started using composite board ripped in half and bedded in silicone as a base for the treated lumber. I also leave occasional gaps between the composite to allow for drainage in case of plumbing leaks.